# SOA + MVC - Where should I populate an entity's properties?

Tags: model-view-controller, language-agnostic, soa

I'm working on an MVC app that makes heavy use of Services. My question is, when creating an entity, should I populate its properties from within the controller, or from within a service?

Example 1 - Populating from within controller:

```
// MyController.php
function someAction() {
  $name = $_POST['name'];
  $gender = $_POST['gender'];

  $user = new User();
  $user->setName($name);
  $user->setGender($gender);

  $userService->createUser($user);
}

// UserService.php
function createUser($user) {
  $this->saveToDb($user);
}
```

Example 2 - Populating from within service:

```
// MyController.php
function someAction() {
  $name = $_POST['name'];
  $gender = $_POST['gender'];

  $userService->createUser($name, $gender);
}

// UserService.php
function createUser($name, $gender) {
  $user = new User();
  $user->setName($name);
  $user->setGender($gender);

  $this->saveToDb($user);
}
```

I like the 2nd approach better, because I feel the controller should simply delegate work out, and the service layer should do the heavy lifting.

It also seems to follow the DRY principle because if I have multiple controllers that need to create `User` objects, I won't be repeating any code. The same goes for writing unit tests - I can simply pass all the arguments to the service object.

But I've seen the first method used as well, and I'm wondering if there's some advantage to it that I'm not seeing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with the second approach, as it is DRY.

The first approach is ok, but instead of DB entity you should be passing DTO, which you can use to populate your DB entity inside the service. I would not expose DB entities from the service, in order to decouple DB layer from presentation layer.